# How to send build package back to teamcity as build artifact when building on agent/client side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, teamcity

Our teamcity server uses Windows OS, so build process checkouts git source to agent Macs, and so build result package (*.ipa package) remains on agent. How to send this *.ipa build package to teamcity server, so it would appear as artifact?

At first, I have assumed teamcity should grab build result - ipa package by itself, so I'v added "OurProject/build/ipa/*.ipa" in "Artifact paths" settings in General settings of build configuration, but no artifacts appear under build result in teamcity website. Probably missing something obvious here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default teamcity searches for artifacts inside workDir/yourCheckoutedSourceDir. My build dir is located at the root of teamcity folder on agent side and I'm using BUILD_DIR environment variable in custom scripts to set where build result should be saved. So and I'v used this environment variable in custom scripts using this format:

```
${BUILD_DIR}
```

My problem was teamcity does not recognize such format when using inside artifact paths field, so you need to use this format instead:

```
%env.BUILD_DIR%
```

If build dir is set to outside of checkout dir then the other solution would be to use relative paths like ../../Builds, but the first solution is more clearer in case the name of build dir would change.

Answer (score 0):

Artifact pattern like:

```
**/*.ipa
```

should publish all these files.
See also: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-artifactPaths